# Excel function for checking if measurement is made on the same day each month?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of field data of approx. 25 years long for 50 locations. I need to check that the measurements are made every month on the same day, the 7th of the month. Except when the 7th is on a sunday or saturday, then the measurement should be made on the friday or the monday. Is there an easy way to check this?

My data looks like this:

| Field Location | Date | Measurement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Loc. A | 08-02-2000 | 1 |
| Loc. A | 11-02-2000 | 4 |
| Loc. A | 07-03-2000 | 1 |
| Loc. A | 07-04-2000 | 2 |
| Loc. B | 08-02-2000 | 7 |
| Loc. B | 11-02-2000 | 9 |
| Loc. B | 07-03-2000 | 8 |
| Loc. B | 10-04-2000 | 1 |
| etc. | etc. | etc. |

I would like to have an output with an overview of each month with a check wether a measurement has been made on the 7th. The measurement itself isn't important for this check.
So something like this (although the exact outcome doesn't bother me):

| Field location | feb. 2000 | mar. 2000 | apr. 2000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Loc. A | no | yes | yes |
| Loc. B | no | yes | no |

I tried using a pivot table. But I can't seem to figure out how to get the saturday/sunday element in there. Additionally the total sums of the pivot table make an overview hard to read.

I hope you guys can help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following dynamic array solution, which will return the output as expected from the OP.

### [image]

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     extract, FILTER(A2:B9,DAY(B2:B9)=F1),
     a, TEXT(DROP(extract,,1),"mmm.yyyy"),
     b, TAKE(extract,,1),
     ua, TOROW(UNIQUE(a)),
     ub, UNIQUE(b),
     c, MMULT(--(TOROW(b)=ub),--(a=ua)),
     HSTACK(VSTACK("Field Location",ub),
     VSTACK(ua,IF(c>0,"Yes","No"))))
```

---

Note: The solution provided is based on specific day of the month here for 7th of each month, but as mentioned in OP, if the 7th falls on Saturday or Sunday then it has to be from Friday or Monday is not considered. For that, the formula needs some modifications, for that you need to provide some example data as well.

---